# Can this Classic Regular Expression be simplified?

Tags: complexity-theory, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I have the following Regular Expression (classic Computer Science definition of Regular Expression, not PCRE or modern computer language RegEx):

{(ΣΣ)*00(ΣΣ)*}Σ ∪ Σ{(ΣΣ)*00(ΣΣ)*}

It "feels" like it should be reducible to me but I can't see how. Is it reducible or am I just asking for trouble trying? The term in {} just generates even-length strings that contain, at least, the substring 00.

Answer (score 1):

$(\Sigma \Sigma)^* (\Sigma 0 0 | 0 0 \Sigma) (\Sigma \Sigma)^* $

You need an even number of letters on the left and an odd number on the right, or the other way round.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'm just envisioning the equivalent NFA and I think your answer is cleaner. Now let me see if I can derive it!